# How to reposition and resize subviews in a view using Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a view in Interface Builder that contains a UITextView and two UIButtons. In portrait mode I want the view to look like this:
[image]

And in landscape mode I want the view to automatically reposition/resize things so that it looks like this:
[image]

I'm assuming that some combination of Size & Position, Autosizing, Alignment and Placement properties for the various views and subviews could achieve this, but despite experimenting with a bunch of combinations I can't even get remotely close to what I'm trying to achieve.

Is this even possible, or should I concentrate on repositioning everything programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Set up your options like this:

TextView: Fixed top, bottom, left and right margins. Flexible width and height

[image]

OK button: Fixed left and bottom margins. Fixed width and height

[image]

Cancel button: Fixed right and bottom margins. Fixed width and height

[image]

Position the views correctly in portrait mode in IB and everything should resize correctly for landscape mode and preserve the layout.

EDIT to show where to find settings.

[image]

Comment: Where do I set these properties in IB? I'm not seeing anything like this.

Comment: Edited to show right-hand Utilities panel in Xcode 4. Select the 'Size Inspector' (a little ruler icon). Xcode3/IB has similar settings.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Weird, though, because I thought that I had tried that exact combination of settings, without success (obviously I didn't, though).